# Float Left, Float Right - Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm having trouble floating elements left and right. You can see what I want to float left and right [here](http://jakesdiner.incredifull.com/menu/). You can see which elements I want left and right in the header.

This is using a plugin, but still can be styled like HTML. Here is some relevant HTML:

```
<div id="menuHeader">
<h2>Appetizers Left</h2>
</div>
[tbl width="425" colwidth="50|50" colalign="left|right"]
Onion Rings,4.95
Fries,3.99
Nachos Supreme (small),8.95
Nachos Supreme (large),10.95
[/tbl]

<div id="menuHeader">
<h2>Fresh Salads Right</h2>
</div>
[tbl width="425" colwidth="100|50|50" colalign="left|right|right"]
,Small,Large
Garden Salad,4.95,5.99
Chef | Caesar| Greek,5.95,6.95
Add chicken for,,2.00
[/tbl]
```

Comment: Please share your CSS too!!

Comment: Did any of the supplied answers below solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap each header and associated table in a div like so and apply the floats to that container.

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu-container left">
    <div id="menuHeader">
        <h2>Appetizers Left</h2>
    </div>
    [tbl width="425" colwidth="50|50" colalign="left|right"]
    Onion Rings,4.95
    Fries,3.99
    Nachos Supreme (small),8.95
    Nachos Supreme (large),10.95
    [/tbl]
</div>

<div class="menu-container right">
    <div id="menuHeader">
        <h2>Fresh Salads Right</h2>
    </div>
    [tbl width="425" colwidth="100|50|50" colalign="left|right|right"]
    ,Small,Large
    Garden Salad,4.95,5.99
    Chef | Caesar| Greek,5.95,6.95
    Add chicken for,,2.00
    [/tbl]
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.menu-container.left { float: left; }
.menu-container.right { float: right; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You need wrappers around your relevant sections

<div class="leftFloat">
<div id="menuHeader">
<h2>Appetizers Left</h2>
</div>
[tbl width="425" colwidth="50|50" colalign="left|right"]
Onion Rings,4.95
Fries,3.99
Nachos Supreme (small),8.95
Nachos Supreme (large),10.95
[/tbl]
</div>


<div class="rightFloat">
<div id="menuHeader">
<h2>Fresh Salads Right</h2>
</div>
[tbl width="425" colwidth="100|50|50" colalign="left|right|right"]
,Small,Large
Garden Salad,4.95,5.99
Chef | Caesar| Greek,5.95,6.95
Add chicken for,,2.00
[/tbl]
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
```

The relevant styles in your css styles.

```
.leftFloat{ float:left; }
.rightFloat{ float:right; }

.clear{ clear:both; }
```

Read more about floating elements here: http://html.net/tutorials/css/lesson13.php

Answer (score 0):

You have to put all your content inside of a div and to use style="float:right/left" according that you need.

```
<div style="float:left">
<div id="menuHeader">
<h2>Appetizers Left</h2>
</div>
[tbl width="425" colwidth="50|50" colalign="left|right"]
Onion Rings,4.95
Fries,3.99
Nachos Supreme (small),8.95
Nachos Supreme (large),10.95
[/tbl]
</div>

<div style="float:right">
<div id="menuHeader">
<h2>Fresh Salads Right</h2>
</div>
[tbl width="425" colwidth="100|50|50" colalign="left|right|right"]
,Small,Large
Garden Salad,4.95,5.99
Chef | Caesar| Greek,5.95,6.95
Add chicken for,,2.00
[/tbl]
</div>
```